# Facebook Login Authentication

Tags: c#, facebook, razor, helper

I have a website where users can login using facebook. Users can register with their facebook account and that's fine.

the problem is if they return to my site but they are already logged into Facebook.
how do I then log them into my site automatically?

I'm using the Razor Facebook helper.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the JavaScript SDK for Facebook?

In that case you can use the [FB.getLoginStatus()](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) method to determine if they are logged in into Facebook.

The code in question looks like this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (res) {
  if (res.authResponse) {
    //User is authenticated with FB and your app
    //You can now load the Facebook User through FB.get('/me')
  } else 
  {
    FB.login(function () {
      //Callback once the user logged into FB and gave your app permission
      //Same as above
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the facebook javascript SDK documentation - [FB.getLoginStatus()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) :

> To determine if a user is connected to your app:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and connected to your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    //but not connected to the app
  } else {
    // the user isn't even logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```